# Using tocloft and parskip generates a warning about redefining \@starttoc

Tags: warnings, tocloft, parskip

If you use both `tocloft` and `parskip` packages, a warning is generated about the redefinition of `\@starttoc`.

The MWE is straightforward. This code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{Section}
    Some text
\end{document}
```

generates the warning

```
Package tocloft Warning: \@starttoc has already been redefined; tocloft bailing out. on input line 1147.
```

while, reverting the loading order of the two packages, the warning becomes

```
LaTeX Warning: Command \@starttoc  has changed. Check if current package is valid.
```

I looked inside the code of the two packages, and they look quite similar in the definition of `\@starttoc`. Nonetheless, the output PDF looks exactly the same.

Is it safe to ignore this warning? Otherwise how can it be removed? Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In 2022, the solution is quite simple. Just load `parskip` after `tocloft`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{parskip}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{Section}
    Some text
\end{document}
```

Parskip can now easily handle the changes tocloft makes, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 5):

The redefinitions in the two packages are different. The `parskip` package makes sure that in the ToC the `\parskip` is zero (which it is in most documents). The `tocloft` package adds hooks at the start and end of the ToC but does nothing with the `\parskip`. You are probably OK if you call `tocloft` before `parskip` and ignore `parskip`'s warning. If you call `parskip` before `tocloft` then `tocloft` capabilities will not be available in your document. Others might give better answers as to how to use the two packages together.